# mongoose post hook get previous state of document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to somehow grab the previous doc before it was saved in a mongoose post hook?

I need to do a compare between the 2 states, before and after to know what has changed and then act accordingly.

Comment: Do you need the full previous data, or just to know what fields have changed?

Comment: just to know which fields have changed